# SUBSTITUTE within ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to perform a text replacement over multiple cells. I'm sure I can do this using ARRAYFORMULA, but I'm not sure how to feed SUBSTITUTE with an array rather than a single value.

I have tried using `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, '&amp;', '&'))` but this gives a formula parse error.

What is the correct formula to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the double quotation marks `"` instead of the single quotation marks `'`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "&amp;", "&"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is about the hundredth time that Sheets has caught me out with the double-quotes requirement. I wish it were a bit more JavaScript-like!

Comment: We can't see your sheet and don't know your application / end goal. But have you considered in-place replacement using simple Find / Replace (Ctrl-H)?

Comment: @ErikTyler that wouldn't work - Find/Replace is a one-off operation, whereas SUBSTUTE works with the current value of a cell. Every week I receive data incorrectly formatted, so I have a column which translates it into the correct format using SUBSTITUTE.

(Running Find/Replace on the new data every week would be tedious & error-prone)